# Symfony 4 with Material Bootstrap Select Picker not being submitted

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, material-design, symfony4

**Setup**

1. PHP 7.1.3
2. Symfony 4
3. Bootstrap 4
4. Twig 4.3
5. JQuery / Ajax

All being run in docker containers (MySQL 8 and nginx)

For styling, I am using Creative Tim's Bootstrap Material Dashboard (https://www.creative-tim.com/product/material-dashboard-pro)

**Issue**

So, using Symfony 4 forms and creating a standard drop-down select works without error when using custom blocks for the rendering:

```
{%- block choice_widget_collapsed -%}
    {% if attr.hidden is not defined or attr.hidden == false %}
        {%- set attr = attr|merge({class: (attr.class|default('') ~ ' selectpicker')|trim}) -%}
    {% endif %}
    {%- if required and placeholder is none and not placeholder_in_choices and not multiple and (attr.size is not defined or attr.size <= 1) -%}
        {% set required = false %}
    {%- endif -%}
    <select {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if multiple %} multiple="multiple"{% endif %} class="{% if required %}required{% endif %} bmd-label-static"
                                                                                             data-style="select-with-transition">
        {%- if placeholder is not none -%}
            <option value=""{% if required and value is empty %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ placeholder != '' ? (translation_domain is same as(false) ? placeholder : placeholder|trans({}, translation_domain)) }}</option>
        {%- endif -%}
        {%- if preferred_choices|length > 0 -%}
            {% set options = preferred_choices %}
            {{- block('choice_widget_options') -}}
            {%- if choices|length > 0 and separator is not none -%}
                <option disabled="disabled">{{ separator }}</option>
            {%- endif -%}
        {%- endif -%}
        {%- set options = choices -%}
        {{- block('choice_widget_options') -}}
    </select>
{%- endblock choice_widget_collapsed -%}
```

Whenever I submit a form which has a select in the base form, the select option is passed back to the controller (using ajax) as part of the form.

However, when the form is a collection type within a form (prototyping entities) as below:

```
$builder
    ->add('billRatesInput',
        CollectionType::class,
        [
            'entry_type' => BillRatesInputForm::class,
            'entry_options' =>
                [
                    'label' => false,
                    'disabled' => $options['isDisabled']
                ],
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
        ]

    )
;
```

When the parent form is submitted, it takes all the parent form values and all the child form (`BillRatesInputForm`) except the values associated with the select fields.

If I remove the block template and allow the rendering to be a basic select box, the submission works without error, but with the block template, the submission does not work, but only on the child forms.